# ASP MVC-3 : Problems updating the data of an AJAX form after making a post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have the following problem when updating a for via AJAX after it is submitted. For some reason some hidden fields that are on the HTML that is returned are not being updated, which is weird because when I run the debugger they appeared to have the correct value.

This is the relevant part of my form

```
<div id="itemPopUpForm">
    @{Html.EnableClientValidation();}
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div id="formDiv">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("ItemData", Model, new ViewDataDictionary() { { "Machines", ViewBag.Machines }, { "WarehouseList", ViewBag.WarehouseList }, { WebConstants.FORM_ID_KEY, @ViewData[WebConstants.FORM_ID_KEY] } }); }
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the partial view contains hidden fields like these which are the ones not being updated

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Item", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmItem", name = "frmItem" }))
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Item.SodID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Item.ItemID) //The itemID needs updating when an item is copied
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Item.Delivery.DeliveryAddressID, new { @id = "delAddressID" })
```

And this is the javascript method that updates the form

```
function ajaxSave() {
        if (!itemValid()) return; 
        popup('ajaxSplash');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Index")',
            data: $("#frmItem").serialize(),
            success: function (html) {
                console.log(html);
                $("#formDiv").html(html);
                initItemPage();
                alert("Item was saved successfully");
            },
            error: function () { popup('ajaxSplash'); onFailure(); }
        });
    }
```

The action Index returns the Partial View "ItemData" and when I check the Item Model it does have the correct value, but when I see the html returned it is still set to 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you intend to modify a model property in your POST action don't forget to remove it from ModelState first, otherwise HTML helpers will use the originally posted value when rendering:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    // remove the value from modelstate
    ModelState.Remove("Item.ItemID");

    // update the value
    model.Item.ItemID = 2;   

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to have worked, but it has left me with more questions about this issue. Why was this not being updated, but the following Helper:

    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Item.Delivery.Instructions) 

was being updated correctly?? Is it something peculiar of the Hidden fields?

Also, since I'm updating many fields is there a way to do the ModelState.Remove() in a global scale?

Comment: You could use `ModelState.Clear()` to remove all values from the ModelState. As far as the TextAreaFor helper is concerned, it should act the same way as the HiddenFor helper. There's nothing special about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and it seems like the helper `HiddenFor` evaluates with required unobtrusive validation even if in the model one does not annotate the property with `[Required]`.

The HTML rendered by `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Step)` is :

`<input data-val=​"true" data-val-number=​"The field Step must be a number." data-val-required=​"The Step field is required." id=​"Step" name=​"Step" type=​"hidden" value=​"2">​`

Hence, it is why it works if we remove it from the `ModelState`.

Removing the property from the ModelState seems to me like a hack. I would prefer to use

`<input type="hidden" id="Step" name="Step" value="@Model.Step" />`

instead of the `Html.HiddenFor` helper.

You can also implement you own HiddenFor helper.